# Vector of shared_ptrs behaves mysteriously

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, vector, shared-ptr

I created a vector of `Base` class `shared_ptr`s to hold `Derived` class `shared_ptr`s, and running into some problems.

The following simplified example shows what happens.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
    Base(int i) : val(i) {}
    int val;
};

class Derived : public Base {
  public:
    Derived(int i) : Base(i) {}  
};

int main()
{
    vector<shared_ptr<Base>> vec1{
        make_shared<Base>(5),
        make_shared<Base>(99),
        make_shared<Base>(18)};

    for (auto const e : vec1)
        cout << e->val << endl;
    cout << endl;

    vector<shared_ptr<Derived>> vec2{
        make_shared<Derived>(5),
        make_shared<Derived>(99),
        make_shared<Derived>(18)};

    for (auto const e : vec2)
        cout << e->val << endl;
    cout << endl;

    vector<shared_ptr<Base>> vec3{
        make_shared<Derived>(5),
        make_shared<Derived>(99),
        make_shared<Derived>(18)};

    for (auto const e : vec3)
        cout << e->val << endl;
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this on my machine (Win7 64bit with MS VS2013) I get the following output:

```
5
99
18

5
99
18

-572662307
99
18
```

What am I missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: [Works correctly on gcc 4.8.1](https://ideone.com/OPnVoS)

Comment: As far as I can tell, the output you posted doesn't correspond with the output of the code. I copied your code to ideone and the output was correct (see https://ideone.com/2Y33lW).

Comment: Looks like you hit [this bug](http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814697/first-element-of-vector-is-destroyed-initializing-from-initializer-list).

Comment: That is very strange. It should work, even without a virtual destructor. But could you try adding an empty virtual destructor to `Base`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Verified it here too, the first element is getting destroyed. The [original bug report is here](http://www.beta.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/807610/first-element-of-vector-is-destroyed-initializing-from-initializer-list).

It seems to happen when you initialize a vector with an initializer list in certain circumstances. 
And their response was `The fix should show up in the **future release** of Visual C++.`

Comment: Thank you! I've been banging my head on this :)